# Name for "3D quadrilateral" shape?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, terminology

I am interested to know the name of the following solid construction - kind of a deformed cube... but I don't know the name, or even a general name:

1. Left and right faces parallel with the $yz$ axes
2. Bottom face parallel with the $xz$ axes
3. Back face parallel with the $xy$ axes.
4. Front and top faces not necessarily parallel,

assuming $x=(1, 0, 0),y=(0,1,0),z=(0,0,1)$. If there is no such name, then is "3d quadrilateral" correct ?

Comment: I would not call "quadrilateral" what seems to be a solid. "Cuboid" might be a more appropriate name.

Comment: Just found this: I think maybe polyhedron might cover it (in general). A polyhedron with 6 faces is called a hexahedron. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hexahedron.html

Comment: To my knowledge there's no standard name for such a shape, but if I understand the description your solid is a [prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_%28geometry%29), over a [right trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid) if the top and bottom (or front and back) faces are parallel, over a nameless quadrilateral otherwise. "Quadrilateral prism" is probably self-descriptive, but an appropriate name depends on context and your intended usage.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I will have a think about your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a right-quadrilateral-based right prism. Say prism for short.

Answer (score -2):

It is called Triclinic. It is one of the 7 crystal systems.
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triclinic_crystal_system)

Comment: Not at all. This is not a parallelepiped and some angles are right.